# Spectral theorem for self-adjoint differential operator on Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mp.mathematical-physics, sp.spectral-theory, sturm-liouville-theory

I need a reference concerning a theorem that shows the following result, stated very roughly:

Given a self-adjoint differential operator densely defined on a Hilbert space, then the given Hilbert space is spanned by the eigenvectors of the operator.

Notes:

1) The statement above is very rough since for example, the continuous spectrum (which does not correspond to eigenvectors in the space) has to be used.

2) The operator I am thinking about are defined on the whole line (so there is continuous spectrum).

3) I am really looking for a spectral theorem for differential operators on the whole line. One issue I have is that in most of the books, they prove such theorems for bounded and/or compact operators only.

4) Another way to phrase is to look at the Sturm-Liouville theory as stated in [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) and be able to say something about the basis when a and b are infinite.

Comment: Weidmann's book is an excellent reference on the questions you mention. http://books.google.hu/books/about/Linear_operators_in_Hilbert_spaces.html?id=_SDvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y

Comment: To be concrete let's take $\partial_x^2$ defined on $H^2(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$.  What do you mean by eigenvectors? The solutions to the eigenvector equation $u_{xx} = \lambda u$ don't live in $L^2$.  If we think of an orthonormal system of eigenvectors as forming the columns of an orthogonal matrix which diagonalizes the operator, perhaps the appropriate generalization is to seek a unitary transformation (Fourier Transform) which conjugates the operator with multiplication (by $-k^2$).  

Comment: You are perfectly right but I am thinking in physical term when you have an observable (self-adjoint linear diff. operator) whose "eigenvectors" generate the whole physical space (i.e. $L^2$). The eigenvectors corresponding to the continuous spectrum are unphysical but they can be added continuously in the form of an integral. In your example, there is only continuous spectrum but the Fourier series is a continuous sum over the unphysical solutions of the eigenvalue problem.   

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For differential (especially, for Sturm--Liouville) operators I would recommend Akhiezer, Glazman's "Theory of linear operators in Hilbert space" and Naimark's "Linear differential operators".

In von Neumann's classical book "Mathematical foundations of quantum mechanics" the spectral theorem is stated very roughly.

Answer (score 11):

Reed & Simon, [*Methods of modern mathematical physics I: Functional analysis*](http://books.google.nl/books?id=fXX0j4qa8G8C) (Academic Press, 1980): Chapter VIII, Section 3, Theorem VIII.6 (combined with property (b) of a *projection-valued measure*, *loc. cit.*). Of course, you'd have to first prove that your differential operator is at least essentially self-adjoint.

Answer (score 6):

You might also be interested in a more general version of the theorem, which, while more technical, IMHO, is much more elegant.

> **Theorem** A self-adjoint operator in a rigged Hilbert space has a complete system of generalized eigenvectors, corresponding to real generalized eigenvalues.

This is Theorem 5' in Subsection I.4.5 of Volume 4 of I. M. Gelfand's *Generalized Functions* (on pg. 126).  They define generalized eigenvectors and eigenvalues as follows.

> Let $A$ be a linear operator on a linear topological space $\Phi$.  A linear functional $F$ on $\Phi$, such that
>   $$
> F(A\phi )=\lambda F(\phi )
> $$
>   for every element $\phi$ of $\Phi$, is called *a generalized eigenvector of the operator $A$, corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$*.

(This can be found on pg. 105 of the same text.)

The nice thing about this formulation is that (1) you don't have to worry about operators being only densely-defined (if their dense domain gives the Hilbert space the structure of a rigged Hilbert space, you can extend the operator (it must be self-adjoint) to the entire rigged Hilbert space) and (2) you don't have to formulate the theorem in terms of projection-valued measures (this is somewhat unnatural), but can formulate it in terms of honest-to-god eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

In fact, in general, I would recommend looking into the theory of rigged Hilbert spaces.  According to Gelfand himself (pg. 105 of the same text):

> We believe this concept [of a rigged Hilbert space] is no less (if indeed not more) important than that of a Hilbert space.

I am inclined to agree.

Comment: What does "generalized eigenvector" mean in this context? (I am only familiar with the usage from linear algebra.) In particular, what is a generalized eigenvector for the *bounded*, self-adjoint operator $(M f)(t) = tf(t)$ on $L^2[0,1]$?

Comment: Yemon, a generalized eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$ in your case is just $\delta_{\lambda}$, a tempered distribution. And this what you want to do: extend Hilbert space to some space which includes objects that you would think of as eigenvectors. Maybe a more natural example would be differentiation ($i \frac{d}{dx}$) which obviously have exponentials ("plane waves") as eigenvectors, however they are not square-integrable.


Comment: I want to add that I do not agree that formulation of spectral theorem with projection-valued measures is unnatural: first, it is more geometric (does not refer to any basis; that is what I like about it even in finite-dimensional case) and it is quite well motivated that projections should correspond to (elementary) observables in quantum mechanics and spectral theorem says then that all self-adjoint operators ought to do so.

Comment: @Yemon Choi I've added a verbatim copy of their definition of generalized eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @Mateusz Wasilewski I mean that it is unnatural in the sense that the project-valued measured formulation of the theorem is not presented in a way that is actually used in practice (by physicists).  Most physicists probably don't even know what a measure is, much less a projection-valued measure, on the other hand, they all know what an eigenvector and eigenvalue is.  To be fair, they likewise probably also don't know what the term "generalized" here means, but you could just pass that off as technical machinery required to make what's going on under the hood work; they idea is still the same.

Comment: Having explained this in more detail, I'm thinking that "unnatural" isn't the best word for what I meant, because I would likewise argue that a basis-independent formulation is always going to be more natural than a basis-dependent one.  In any case, hopefully it is more clear what I meant.

Comment: Jonathan, thank you for clearing it up. I think it is best to always have in mind many equivalent forms of spectral theorem and I agree with you that this one is extremely valuable, because this is how physicists usually think of spectral decomposition.

Comment: As nice as this theorem might be, there is a catch, isn't there? The operator A has to be $\Phi\to\Phi$ and it does not apply to a general selfadjoint operator $\Phi\to H$, right? For differential operators this might not be as much of a problem since we know that the Schwartz space exists, but what about less familiar operators?

Comment: @JohannesHahn, for "semi-bounded" operators, at least, the somewhat-richer context you observe for (let's say elliptic) differential operators _can_ be set up. So something a bit more than "Gelfand triples" can indeed be formalized... but/and I think in the same spirit.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Can you give an example of such an operator?  I have to admit, in all the examples I was interested in (all differential operators), you could choose always $\Phi$ so that we had $A:\Phi \rightarrow \Phi$.

Comment: I have to admit, I think the Hilbert space itself is a bit superfluous and is only mentioned explicitly in the definition for historical reasons.  I usually think of rigged spaces as topological vectors spaces $\Phi$ equipped with an embedding into their conjugate dual $\Phi \hookrightarrow \Phi ^*$.  This then gives a sesqui-linear form on $\Phi$, which we can complete to get a Hilbert space if we really want it, but I try to avoid mentioning the Hilbert space directly if I can.  From this perspective, considering examples which explicitly mention the Hilbert space feels a bit weird to me.

Comment: @JonathanGleason What about differential operators with non-polynomial coefficients? I guess it is possible to find an appropriate space $\Phi$ in many cases, but I don't think there is a general theorem to this end.

Comment: Suppose we have a partially-defined (un-boudned) operator $A:L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and define $\Phi :=\left\{ f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):A^n(f)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\text{ for all }n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.  Unless I am being incredibly dense, $A$ should restrict to an operator $A|_{\Phi}:\Phi \rightarrow \Phi$.  This should always work, though in bad cases we will probably have $\Phi =0$.

Comment: Question:  Let us generalize this definition to the case where a single operator $A$ is replaced by an algebra $\mathcal{A}$:  $\Phi :=\left\{ f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}):A(f)\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\text{ for all }A\in \mathcal{A}\right\}$.  For $\mathcal{A}$ the algebra generated by the usual position and momentum operators, does this definition give us the Schwartz space?

Comment: @JonathanGleason Not only can this space be zero. Even if it isn't zero it might still fail to be dense. Also: unbounded operators do not form algebras in general because of the need to keep track of the various domains. If you define the domain of $A+B$ to be $dom(A)\cap dom(B)$ (which is the most obvious choice) then even addition isn't assoziative and doesn't admit negatives.

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual proof of the generalized eigenvector expansion given in the 4th volume of Generalized Functions is completely wrong. See Gould's [The Spectral Representation of Normal Operators on a Rigged Hilbert Space](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s1-43.1.745/abstract) for a correct proof. While I like the idea of rigged Hilbert spaces myself, the tricky details around the existence of liftings mean that it's easy to make stupid mistakes, apparently even for the originators of the theory.

Answer (score 3):

A newer reference is

Unbounded Self-adjoint Operators on Hilbert Space by Konrad Schmüdgen

http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-94-007-4753-1

The desired result is a consequence of Theorem 5.7 (p.89) combined with Proposition 15.14 (p.358), Definition 4.2 (p.66), Theorem 4.6 (p.68) and the unlabeled displayed  definition at the bottom of page 73.

Comment: Where in the book is the theorem is discussed?

Answer (score 1):

Look up Mautner´s theorem as presented in Dieudonne Treatise on Analysis Vol. 10-VII. There is a nice presentation of the spectral theorem in the language of generalized eigenfunctions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the book *Analysis Now* by G.K. Pedersen, which has two nice chapters on Spectral Theory and Unbounded Operators.

[Klick here to see the book at Springer Online](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-1007-8)